# concatenate text field with leading zero in excel

Tags: excel, concatenation

I have **Column A** with  CA- and **Column B** 0000197222 ( 10 digits Number) . I need to Concat Col A and Col B and store the result in Col C and the result should display as CA-0000197222 ( the result should always be 10 digits numeric).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are losing the leading zeros, then it means that column B is not formatted as text, but number with leading zeros. So, try this formula:

```
=A1&TEXT(B1,REPT("0",10))
```

The `REPT` is just repeating the `0` ten times.

Answer (score 0):

```
=A1&B1
```

The ampersand character will concatenate the values in the specified cells.

Comment: This will take out the leading Zero's

Comment: Is the cell formatted as text?

Comment: yes, it is formatted as text

Comment: Here is an example of it working with your 2 values: https://gofile.me/2iedJ/KVpec0Ot